# Unix : hyphen(-) getting replaced by <96>

Tags: linux, unix

Recently, I have written one shell script in Notepad++ on Windows machine. But when I transferred this script to Linux box I observed that the commands containing - (dash or hyphen or minus) sign got replaced with <96>. e.g. the original command is like below -

```
unzip -d $dir_to_unzip file.zip
```

But when transferred to Linux server it became like below-

```
unzip <96>d $dir_to_unzip file.zip
```

I am not an Unix expert and not able to find what is causing this change and how to correct it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `0x96` is the code for the `–` EN DASH character in the Windows-1252 character set. The original command does not have the hyphen character you want; it has a representation of the EN DASH character. The two characters look very similar on Windows, but Linux doesn't use the Windows-1252  character set, so `0x96` is some non-printable control character, which is being rendered as `<96>`. (The Unicode code for EN DASH is `0x2013`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ has a set of menus for specifying the encoding.  A quick check with its default (UTF-8 without BOM) does not give me a non-ASCII text for a simple shell script.  It is possible that you got this example by pasting text into Notepad++ from some webpage (which frequently are misencoded).

However, to ensure that you get the results which you expect, you can override the encoding using Notepad++ menus, and re-save the file.  Besides UTF-8, other possibly useful choices include (via the cascading menu for "Western European"...) ISO-8859-1.

You should avoid using "ANSI" in Notepad++, because it is an ambiguous term which includes the sort of character redefinition which is causing you problems.  For further discussion on this, see

- *[Why can Notepad++ display non-ASCII characters in ANSI encoding correctly but Sublime Text 2 cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250269/why-can-notepad-display-non-ascii-characters-in-ansi-encoding-correctly-but-su)*
- *[notepad++ converting ansi encoded file to utf-8 [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/notepad-converting-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8)*
- *[Notepad++, How to remove all non ascii characters with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/notepad-how-to-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex)*

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to figure out how to type a real (ASCII) minus sign in Notepad, or you'll have to avoid using your Windows machine to edit ASCII text files intended for use on linux or unix hosts.